# Call a function of another exported method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file called `internal.js`, and it looks like this:

```
module.exports = deps => async (event) => {
    console.log(deps.a);
    console.log(aFunction());

    function aFunction() {
        return "This is the aFunction - " + deps.a;
    }
}
```

and another file `external.js` that `require` it, and it looks like this:

```
let internal = require('./internal')({
  a: "this is the a variable"
});

internal();
```

I execute this launching `node external.js` and the result is:

```
➜ node external.js
this is the a variable
This is the aFunction - this is the a variable
```

OK for now. What I would, due to testing reasons, is the ability to invoke directly `aFunction` that is coded inside the `internal.js` (note due to the `deps.a` I cannot move `aFunction` outside the `module.exports`). How can I do?

Comment: can't you call it using `internal.aFunction()` ?

Comment: Nope. `internal.aFunction is not a function`.

Comment: You should choose a different design, this is tricky and doesn't follow any best practice

Comment: @AndreaFranchini have you something better to suggest? I will appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you have `internal.js` exporting nothing but a function. This means `external.js` has access to nothing but this function. Since `aFunction()` is simply a locally defined variable in the exported function, it's out of scope for `external.js` and cannot be accessed.

You have to expose it in any of the following ways:

- Place `aFunction` as a property of an exported object along with your `deps =>` function
- Have your exported function return an object which contains `aFunction`
- Have the inner async function return some value with which you can access `aFunction`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you need to export this `aFunction()` and provide deps as argument:

```js
function aFunction({ a }) {
  return "This is the aFunction - " + a;
}
```

Comment: If I export the function how can I import it? I wouldn't split the internal,js in two

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do?

You can't cause of contexts

As commented, first of all you should change design. For providing an example that suits you're needs i need to know them. First thing: why you `cannot move aFunction outside the module.exports` ?

Here a clean code example:

```
// internal.js
function aFunction(param) {
    return "This is the aFunction - " + param;
}

async function myInternalFuncion(deps) {
    // is async because you need to manage promise here?
    console.log(deps.a)
    console.log(aFunction(deps.a))
}

module.exports = {
    myInternalFuncion,
    aFunction,
}

// external.js
const internal = require('./internal')

internal.aFunction('foobar')
internal.myInternalFuncionl({'a':'foobar'})
```

If you stack up complex/anti-pattern code, then you will get problems